# Recover mysql data from microsoft azure mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, azure, ubuntu

I have a java web application which is deployed on microsoft azure cloud instance.

Environment details :

**Jdk 8,Tomcat 8,MySQL Server 5.5 (NOTE: All the installations are done manually NOT selected from azure console environment)**

Unfortunately I lost some data from my database 1 week before and i don't have backup of that data.

Question is : Can microsoft azure recover mysql dump of 1 week before data for us?

Please help.

Comment: Did you ask the same with Azure support team?

Comment: Hi @RavinderReddy i got a reply from azure support like they can not do anything as the application was not deployed in their environment. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Microsoft Azure support was too bad and could not help us in that.

We had recovered some data based on logs of my application but still, most of the data got lost.

One thing which irritated us in this matter was microsoft azure support even after we subscribed them by paying they had a reply time of 8 hours delay.

So now we moved our all the applications to AWS cloud so that this thing would never happen again.